# Creating a symfony service that can access doctrine

Tags: php, symfony

I have a signupAction inside a controller. I would like this signupAction to call another service which then will create an account. So I created a service called AccountService which extends Controller as I would like to get access to doctrine ($this->getDoctrine()...) in order to save an account to the database. However when i cann my service, it tells me it has no access to the container (null).

```
if (!$this->container->has('doctrine')) {
```

The above line fails as container is null.

This is how I call the service:

```
$accountService = $this->get('app.account');
$accountService->createAccount($account);
```

And i configured it in services.yml as:

```
services:
  app.account:
    class: AppBundle\Service\AccountService
```

Can anyone help me figure out how to get this working? Or as a better ideas how to have services called to deal with database instead of it all in my actions in controllers?

I have symfony 3.2

Comment: You are confusing controllers with services.  In most cases, services will not extend from controllers.  Instead, services are stand alone classes in which you would inject your entity manager or repository.  Skim though this for more details: http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#what-is-a-service

Comment: ah right thanks, just had to figure out the arguments for Doctrine which was @doctrine

Comment: Actually, you probably don't want doctrine but rather the entity manager which would be the '@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager' service.

Comment: except if i have doctrine i can get the entity manager from it

Comment: Sure but why?  One major point of dependency injection is to only inject exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that most people starting from scratch would use ORM, I didn't because I had existing PHP code working with PDO SQL. Here is an example showing how to access Doctrine DB connection:

In [YourBundle]\Resources\config\services.yml

```
services:

     #dependency injection services
         pdo_connection:
              class: [YourBundle]\DependencyInjection\PDOManagement\PdoConnection
              arguments: ["@doctrine.dbal.default_connection"]
```

Then in [YourBundle]\DependencyInjection\PDOManagement\PdoConnection.php

```
<?php
namespace [YourBundle]\DependencyInjection\PDOManagement;

use Doctrine\DBAL;


    class PdoConnection {

        protected $db;

        public function __construct($dbalConnection){
            $this->db = $dbalConnection;
        }

    }
?>
```

this->db of class PdoConnection will have access to the DB connection after constructor.

I let you figure out how to use it according to your need.